# Redux Toolkit Slice Reducer not working when adding non-extra Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm new to the whole Redux thing and tried to use the RTK from the beginning which is a confusing challenge to me so far.

Now I'm trying to add a normal Reducer instead of an extraReducer into my slice and i get weired Results i can't understand. When i remove the reducer declaration at all, everything works as intended. Posts are loaded into the props.

```
var initialState = { entities: [], ids: [], fetchState: "idle", current: 0 };

export const postSlice = createSlice({
    name: "posts",
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        currentPostChanged: (state, action) => {},
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchAll.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.fetchState = "pending";
        },
        [fetchAll.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.fetchState = "rejected";
        },
        [fetchAll.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            var keys = objectFlip(Object.keys(action.payload.entities.posts));
            var posts = Object.values(action.payload.entities.posts);
            state.entities = posts;
            state.ids = keys;
            state.fetchState = "idle";
        },
    },
});
export const postReducer = postSlice.reducer;
```

---

Store Config

```
var storeConfig = {
    reducer: {
        posts: postReducer,
    },
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware()],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
};

const store = configureStore(storeConfig);
```

---

Mapping State

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        posts: state.posts.entities,
        postsIds: state.posts.ids,
    };
}
```

Output before fetching is done

```
posts: {…}
  entities: Object {}
  ids: Array []
```

Output after fetching is done

```
posts: {…}
  entities: Array(28) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
  fetchState: "idle"
  ids: Object { 2: "0", 3: "1", 4: "2", … }
```

---

Render Method in React Component

```
render() {
    if (this.props !== undefined) {
        console.log("Component.render()");
        console.log(this.props);
    } 

    return <div></div>
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that i had the same props variable (props.post) used in mapDispatchToProps by accident.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        posts: state.posts.entities, // <-- declared here
        postsIds: state.posts.ids,
    };
}


const mapDispatchToProps = {
    addPosts: postsLoaded,
    fetchPosts: fetchAll,
    // posts: postSlice.actions.currentPostChanged, <-- and here
    // changed to
    changeCurrentPost: postSlice.action.currentPostChanged,
};
```

After Changing the key in mapDispatchToProps everything worked fine.